# How does Control.Enabled work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have spent several days looking at various resources and am getting more confused. I have several controls in a `.aspx` file: an edit button, a year dropdownlist, and four gridviews with textboxes and dropdownlists in them. The textboxes and dropdownlists in the gridviews start disabled. When the user clicks the edit button, they should enable. This works the first time, but they won't disable again. Here's the relevant code:

```
private void toggleEditMode()
{
    editBtn.CssClass = editBtn.Attributes["mode"].ToString() == "edit" ? "btn btn-success" : "btn btn-primary";
    editBtn.Text = editBtn.Attributes["mode"].ToString() == "edit" ? "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'></span>&nbsp;Save" : "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>&nbsp;Edit";
    editBtn.Attributes["mode"] = editBtn.Attributes["mode"].ToString() == "edit" ? "save" : "edit";

    selectYear.Enabled = !selectYear.Enabled;
    foreach (GridView gv in panels)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
        {
            TextBox name = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("nameTB");
            DropDownList rating = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ratingDDL");

            name.Enabled = !name.Enabled;
            rating.Enabled = !rating.
        }
    }
}
```

The edit button turns into the save button properly, and the year dropdownlist toggles correctly, but the textboxes and dropdownlists in the gridview won't disable. During debugging, I have discovered that the `Enabled` property of each textbox and DDL is false at the beginning of this method.

The textboxes and DDL's all **start** disabled, enable on the button click, and then won't disable, even though the button and year DDL toggle correctly.

My question is: how exactly does the `Enabled` property work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** here is the markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="editBtn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="ToggleEditMode" CssClass="btn btn-primary" mode="edit">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit
</asp:LinkButton>

<div class="form-inline" role="form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectYear">Year:&nbsp;</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="selectYear" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And here is the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="jrSchools1a2aAdmin" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" ClientIDMode="Static" OnRowCreated="BindRatings" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <Columns>        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="nameTB" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" schoolID='<%# Eval("schoolID") %>' Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ratingDDL" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Eval("rating") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="students" HeaderText="Students" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="7_1" HeaderText="7-I" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="7_2" HeaderText="7-II" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="8_1" HeaderText="8-I" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="8_2" HeaderText="8-II" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="open" HeaderText="Open" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="score" HeaderText="Score" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

`ToggleEditMode` checks if it should save or not, runs a SQL query if it should save, and calls `toggleEditMode()`.

**EDIT 2:** Here is where `toggleEditMode()` is called. Sorry for the confusion. It's not called anywhere else.

```
protected void ToggleEditMode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (editBtn.Attributes["mode"].ToString() == "save")
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        List<SQLParameter> parameters = new List<SQLParameter>();

        //Determine the year
        int year;
        int.TryParse(selectYear.SelectedItem.Value, out year);
        parameters.Add(new SQLParameter("@year", year));

        // Use a counter so we can enumerate parameter names
        int i = 0;
        foreach (GridView gv in panels)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
            {
                TextBox name = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("nameTB");
                DropDownList rating = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ratingDDL");

                name.CssClass = "form-control green";

                //SQL statements here

                parameters.Add(new SQLParameter(String.Format("@name{0}", i), name.Text));
                parameters.Add(new SQLParameter(String.Format("@schoolID{0}", i), name.Attributes["schoolID"].ToString()));
                parameters.Add(new SQLParameter(String.Format("@rating{0}", i), rating.SelectedValue));

                i++;
            }
        }

        SqlConn.doQuery(query.ToString(), parameters);

        //populateTables();
    }
    toggleEditMode();
}
```

Comment: The link you provided for documentation seems to be for WinForms, not web forms, perhaps the documentation is different for web forms?

Comment: this might be what you're looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I corrected the link. I'm still confused, as it seems my code should work based on the example they gave.

Comment: My guess is you've set the property in the markup and the page is doing a full postback. Please show the markup and where you call the function you've shown above `toggleEditMode()`

Comment: are the buttons added with `runat=server` IIRC this is a requirement for controlling the buttons

Comment: @Jaxi The buttons have `runat='server'`, yes, but the textboxes and dropdownlists are the controls having the problem. They also have `runat='server'`.

Comment: @mjw I am setting `Enabled="false"` in the markup. How else am I supposed to make them start out disabled? I tried setting their Enabled property programmatically on page load in an `if (!IsPostBack)` block, but it didn't work, either.

Comment: @silvertiger Are you by any chance DataBind()ing your GridView on every postback? DataBinding a GridView recreates all the contained controls; any control properties not specified in the ASPX effectively lose values that were set since the controls were created.

Comment: That's a start, but we need to see *where* you call the function `toggleEditMode()` - is it in the Page Load? My guess is either there or a button handler, maybe both...

Comment: @DanielO I am not databinding on every postback. I have that commented out for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @mjw mentioned in the comments, I was setting `Enabled='false'` in the markup. Due to the [page life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)), the controls were always rendering as `Enabled='false'`. If controls can be enabled/disabled based on conditions, this is best handled in the `Page_Load` function. However, ASP.NET has editing capabilities built into the `GridView` control, and these should be preferred over AJAX submissions for the inherent security benefits built into ASP.NET. Here are some links to get you started:

[Making a column editable in an ASP.net GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376378/making-a-column-editable-in-an-asp-net-gridview)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972948(v=msdn.10)

Comment: What security benefits are you talking about?

Comment: For this specific example, `Enabled='false'` can only be changed by the server, meaning an attacker can't use the Inspector to enable the fields and submit unauthorized changes. This application showed data to all users and allowed admins to edit it. Since enabling the input fields is handled by the server, it is impossible to make changes without being signed in as an admin. This is handled in `Page_load()` and meant I only had to write this once and include a conditional without having to worry about security.

Comment: Disabling it prevents the HTML input from going to the user's browser. The users browser can still submit whatever data it wants. If you're using any data provided by the user, you still need to verify it.

Comment: Right, but if the control is disabled, the input will be ignored since it wasn't expected.

Comment: ASP.NET also helps protect against script exploits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/w1sw53ds%28v%3dvs.140%29

Comment: Your link doesn't explain how disabling/enabling controls leads to better security. It's true that it should ignore the user input. But it really depends on the specifics of the implementation. For example, if you have a user control that's disabled, but then when a user submits the form you choose to do an AJAX post instead of a normal HTML form post, then whether the control was enabled or disabled or not is irrelevant. So the point stands: don't trust any user input. Always validate it.

Comment: My point was not about user input at all, my point was to use the editing functionality provided by ASP.NET instead of using AJAX. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The editing functionality provided by ASP.NET relies on user input. It's important for you to remember that ASP.NET Web Forms is not magic. You still must validate any user input that is provided to ensure they have not manipulated it. Clients can do anything, and you have to guard against that on the server side.

Comment: Must it be checked again for script exploits or just to validate the data for the database?

Comment: Everything. For example, you need to guard against SQL Injection attacks, cross site scripting attempts and other vulnerabilities, but also against data manipulations that don't make sense for your domain. For example, let's say you have a label that shows the price of the items in a user's virtual shopping  cart. Now, you haven't provided any way for a user to manipulate this label on the page. But if the user was to submit use JavaScript to modify the value of the label, and then your server side code was to trust the value on the label, that'd be very bad.

Comment: In the shopping cart example, the way to guard against that is to recalculate the price of the shopping cart on submit instead of re-using the label that shows your previous cart price calculation. If it comes from a user, it can't be trusted.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for clarification. Do you have any suggestions for how I can edit my answer to make it better?